# Backtracking algorithm with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to implement an algorithm that takes in two ints n and k where n is the number of seats in a row, and k is the number of students trying to sit in that row.  The thing is that each student must be at least two seats from each other on both side.  What I have is a function that generates all subsets (an array of either 0 or 1 s, 1 meaning someone is sitting there)  and I send this to a function to check to see if it is a valid subset.  This is the code I have for that function

```
def process(a,num,n):
    c = a.count('1')
    #If the number of students sitting down (1s) is equal to the number k, check the subset
    if(c == num):
        printa = True
        for i in range(0,n):
            if(a[i] == '1'):
                if(i == 0):
                    if( (a[i+1] == '0') and (a[i+2] == '0') ):
                        break
                    else:
                        printa = False
                elif(i == 1):
                    if( (a[i-1] == '0') and (a[i+1] == '0') and (a[i+2] == '0') ):
                        break
                    else:
                        printa = False
                elif(i == (n-1)):
                    if( (a[i-2] == '0') and (a[i-1] == '0') and (a[i+1] == '0') ):
                        break
                    else:
                        printa = False
                elif(i == n):
                    if( (a[i-2] == '0') and (a[i-1] == '0') ):
                        break
                else:
                    printa = False                    
            else:
                if( (a[i-2] == '0') and (a[i-1] == '0') and (a[i+1] == '0') and (a[i+2] == '0') ):
                    break
                else:
                    printa = False
        if(printa):
            print a
    else:
        return
```

The code works for small inputs of k and n but if I get higher values I get an index out of list error for some reason I can't figure out.
Any help out be great thanks.

O the input a is the list that looks something like this

```
['1','0','0','1','0'] # a valid subset for n=5 and k=2
['0','0','0','1','1'] # an invalid subset
```

EDIT:

Code that calls process:

```
'''
This function will recursivly call itself until it gets down to the leaves then sends that
subset to process function.  It appends
either a 0 or 1 then calls itself
'''
def seatrec(arr,i,n,k):
    if(i==n):
        process(arr,k,n)
        return
    else:
        arr.append("0")
        seatrec(arr,i+1,n,k)
        arr.pop()
        arr.append("1")
        seatrec(arr,i+1,n,k)
        arr.pop()
    return
'''
This is the starter function that sets up the recursive calls
'''
def seat(n,k):
    q=[]
    seat(q,0,n,k)

def main():
    n=7
    k=3
    seat(n,k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get if I use these numbers are

```
if( (a[i-2] == '0') and (a[i-1] == '0') and (a[i+1] == '0') ):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include the specific call to `process` that leads to an error, including the values of a, num, and n, so that we can reproduce it. Please also post the error message so we know what line it occurred on :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient to exclude invalid seating arrangements, namely, when the students seat next to each other `['1', '1']` or when there is only one seat between them `['1', '0', '1']` all other arrangements that have correct numbers of `'1'`, and `'0'` are valid, [example](http://ideone.com/7KEYJ):

```
def isvalid(a, n, k):
    if not isinstance(a, basestring):
       a = ''.join(a) # `a` is a list of '1', '0'
    return (len(a) == n and a.count('1') == k and a.count('0') == (n-k) and
            all(p not in a for p in ['11', '101']))
```

There are more efficient algorithms to generate valid subsets without checking all subsets e.g.,

```
def subsets(n, k):
    assert k >= 0 and n >= 0
    if k == 0: # no students, all seats are empty
        yield '0'*n
    elif k == 1 and (n == 1 or n == 2): # the last student at the end of the row
        yield '1' + '0'*(n-1) # either '1' or '10'
        if n == 2: yield '01'
    elif n > 3*(k-1): # there are enough empty seats left for k students
        for s in subsets(n-3, k-1):
            yield '100' + s # place a student
        for s in subsets(n-1, k):
            yield '0' + s   # add empty seat
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/x9Z2f)

```
n, k = 5, 2
for s in subsets(n, k):
    assert isvalid(s, n, k)
    print(s)
```

#### Output

```
10010
10001
01001
```

Answer (score 2):

The indexes for an array of length `n` is from `0` to `n-1`.  Thus accessing `n` is out of list.

The code that generates the lists must have a bug if you haven't noticed this on smaller values.

Comment: Where specifically do you see the array access n? `range(0, n)` doesn't include `n`

Comment: when i == (n-1), a[i+1] is accessed. this is equal to a[n]